Term for someone who dislikes many things vocally
I'm looking for a term that describes someone who not only dislikes many things or categories of things, but expresses these dislikes frequently. I'd prefer a noun, but an adjective will do.
The person I'm trying to describe with this term has expressed dislike for certain books and authors (even the literature of a certain nationality), many foods, cities (and the concept of 'cities' in general), many genres of music, and many people in our local social circle. It is as if this person took the adage "If you've got nothing nice to say, don't say anything at all" and turned it on its head: "If you've got something non-nice to say, say it openly."
Example sentence: After getting to know him better, I've realized that he's a ____.
Things I've considered:

Kvetch, a person who complains a great deal. Problem is that disliking and complaining are quite a bit different, particularly in the context I've outlined above.
Curmudgeon a bad-tempered person, especially an old one. Temper is not the essential characteristic I'm trying to capture.
Debbie Downer or Negative Nancy. Naysayers, pessimists. Again, being pessimistic and believing the worst will happen isn't disliking.

The closest I think I've gotten with LLMs is 'disparager', but apart from being somewhat awkward, it seems that a disparager criticizes people, and not things. (I know I mentioned the person I'm describing also expresses dislike for people, but I primarily want to capture the dislike for things).

Are they cynical or depressed? Generally grumpy? If they hate things because they're popular there's a question about that (and). Hater is often used for someone who hates one particular thing, e.g. Taylor Swift, but if you can't find anything better it can be used broadly...

Carper, nitpicker, etc. I suppose these are the words you're looking for.

'Nitpicker' (must surely express their views, and doesn't have to do so in a rage) is given at the duplicate thread. Other suggestions there are 'fault-finder' and 'bellyacher'; 'captious' and 'cavilling'.

A grumbler is a person who complains a lot, especially about things that are not really very serious, one who is given to utterances of discontent or dissatisfaction.
Example : the motor coach tour would have been okay if I hadn't been paired up with a grumbler who whined through the whole thing.
